# php script not picking data from url on web host server

Tags: php, json

I have some PHP script which is gets json data from other website. It retrieves a URL variable by GET method (email) and on the basis of this variable it gets results from user database which are unique movie codes. Then those codes one by one placed in omdbi.com web api to get results in json object and place in a array which is used to collect json objects and then return at the end a json

But when i do this from my local host server it works and return result as a json 
 like..

```
{

    "movieRecord":[
        {
            "Title":"Frozen",
            "Year":"2013",
            "Rated":"PG",
            "Released":"27 Nov 2013",
            "Runtime":"102 min",
            "Genre":"Animation, Adventure, Comedy",
            "Director":"Chris Buck, Jennifer Lee",
            "Writer":"Jennifer Lee (screenplay)",
        }
    ]

}
```

But when i did this from webhost server it returns nulls to me

```
{

    "movieRecord":[
        null,
        null,
        null
    ]

}
```

What can i do ?

My code:

```
  <?php
    include "conn3.php";


    $get_user_email=@$_GET['email'];


    $query2 = "SELECT id from tbl_login where email='$get_user_email';";
    $hasil2 = mysql_query($query2)or die(mysql_error());
    while ($data2=mysql_fetch_array($hasil2)){

        $id= $data2['id'];

    }

    $query = "SELECT movie from usermovieassoc where userr='$id';";


    $hasil = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($hasil) > 0) {
       $response = array();
    $response["movieRecord"] = array();
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
    {
       $h['movie'] = $data['movie'] ;
       $get_id=$h['movie'];
       $url = file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=$get_id&plot=full&r=json");

       $arr = json_decode($url,true);

       json_encode($arr)   

       array_push($response["movieRecord"], $arr);
    }

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {

        echo  json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: what's the point of `json_encode($arr)`? you don't save the encoded array anywhere, so it's a pointless/useless call. you're also just ASSUMING that the file_get_contents() call actually returned json. never EVER assume success when dealing with external resources. always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: thanks for guiding me. i am beginner i will take care of it.. but can you please tell me the alternative?

Comment: You're also using `mysql_*` functions which have been **deprecated for almost a decade**, and which have even been **completely removed from the latest version of PHP**. You're almost _begging_ to be hacked with this code.

Comment: Well thanks for telling.. and i want to add that this code is just written for the android application and it will return results to android.. 


Well  i will see latest methods of php

Answer (score 1):

1.Get ride of `@`. Newer suppresses error if you var is missing:

```
 $get_user_email= isset($_GET['email'])?@$_GET['email']:false;
 if(!$get_user_email)
    die('not all get params are passed');
```

2.SQl injections. Do not use external data right away especially is you are use it  in db query. You should always to make $vars from GET or POST safe. So do at least:

```
$query2 = 'SELECT `id` from `tbl_login` where email=.'mysql_real_escape_string($get_user_email);
```

3.If you are getting unexpected result debug all vars,results and queries using print_r or var_dump:

```
echo 'get_user_email:'.$get_user_email.'<br/>';

echo 'query 1 ';
print_r($query);

echo 'for each loop data';
print_r($data);

echo 'query 2 ';
print_r($query);
```

This will help you to find exactly why you are getting wrong results or when script went wrong/unexpected way